# How do I 'trust' an external data source in Excel?

Tags: excel, data-connections, external-data-source

I have a tool that uses an external data connection to keep a dashboard updated from single CSV which contains a data log. I don't want anyone touching the log itself and fiddling with it, so I have put together a small dashboard that is fed from the data displayed by the connection.

I have the connection set to update on open and every 10 minutes in the background, but it does not do this. Instead, I need to manually press refresh, whereupon I get the following message:

['Microsoft Office has ifentified a potential security concern' message box example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7jHw.png)

I absolutely trust the source in question, but do not want my user to have to click refresh every now and then to make sure their data is up to date.

How can I make this connection 'trusted' and have this persist through sessions?

*(Apologies if I have missed anything or this isn't the right way to ask this question. I'm new! :) )*

Comment: Add the folder to the trusted location see [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4#:~:text=Add%20a%20trusted%20location,folder%2C%20and%20then%20click%20OK.)

Comment: Much obliged, @RicardoDiaz! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the tool and it's peripherals to a (trusted) shared drive, and no problems.